# Angularjs JavaScript to fast when using PUT in a CRUD SPA

Tags: angularjs, rest, asp.net-web-api, single-page-application

Looking at [a RESTful CRUD SPA with angularjs](http://draptik.github.io/blog/2013/07/28/restful-crud-with-angularjs/) for example.

When using the RESTful approach with Angularjs, I am running into cases where an update/delete/etc. isn't reflected in the list without a hard refresh (F5). It's occurring because the save/update/delete are taking longer than JavaScript takes to run the next command which should update the list.

```
app.controller('UserDetailCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'UserFactory', '$location',
function ($scope, $routeParams, UserFactory, $location) {

    // callback for ng-click 'updateUser':
    $scope.updateUser = function () {
        UserFactory.update($scope.user);  // Before this is done
        $location.path('/user-list');     // this has already fetched the (outdated) list
    };
```

Coming from e.g. .NET MVC where in a situation like this I would return the List of items from the update (return value). The scaffolded Web API controller is RESTful, and it doesn't return anything from POST, PUT, or DELETE.

```
    // DELETE api/<controller>/5
    public **void** Delete(int id)
    {
        // delete...
    }
```

In Angularjs I could imagine a couple approaches to ensure that the List of users is always up to date. (For example maintain a list in the $scope and modify it simultaneously with the POST/PUT/DELETE calls but it seems cumbersome)

What is the best approach in Angularjs using RESTful style to ensure e.g. a list has the accurate up to date data? If there isn't a general approach, what would be the best way to handle it in this example app.

Comment: _Since the Web API controller is RESTful, it doesn't return anything from POST, PUT, or DELETE_ - Being RESTful is no reason not to return anything.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I guess that's just a Web API scaffolding default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could wait for the AJAX request to complete before changing the path:

```
UserFactory.update($scope.user, function() {
    $location.path('/user-list');
});
```

Comment: Ah, the callback. http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_callback.asp Fits perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

In a scenario like this I have used the $http or $resource services.

- https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http
- https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

Using $http you would redirect in the success callback

Using $resource you can redirect inside the promise .$promise.then